# database operation with class

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, class

I want to do all operation like insert, delete, update, etc. on database with class. So, where can I find best stable and updated db class library.

I already started working on it, But now I am stuck with it. As, I dont know how to write various class module for class like for security insert, delete or update etc.

I firstly wanted to check for input data for sql injection ,real escape strings
secondly do any DB operations. I don't know how to actually implement it  with class.

I don't know how to write a class function to achieve it.

```
<?php
/*
@author    :vikrant chauhan
project    :college portal
copyrights :2014-2015
*/

Class vcollege_portal
{

/************************/
     //properties//
/************************/

private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $database;
public  $myconn;

/************************/
   //methods//
/************************/

        function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database)
        {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->connectToDatabase();
        $this->selectDatabase();
        }
/************************/
   //connection//
/************************/

        function connectToDatabase() 
        {
        $conn= mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$conn){
        die ("Cannot connect to the database");}
        else{$this->myconn = $conn;
        echo "Connection established";}
        return $this->myconn;
        }
        function selectDatabase() 
        {
        mysql_select_db($this->database); 
        if(mysql_error()) {
        echo "Cannot find the database ".$this->database;}
        echo "Database selected..";       
        }
        function closeConnection() 
        {
        mysql_close($this->myconn);
        echo "Connection closed";
        }
/************************/
   //database security //
/************************/


/************************/
   //database insert //
/************************/


/************************/
   //database update //
/************************/


/************************/
   //database delete //
/************************/

}
?>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions you are using are deprecated (and they won't work with an oracle database).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. But, for you it's important to get the concepts.

Please see it and work accordingly.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-php-class-based-querying--net-11863

Answer (score 0):

U could take a look if PEAR (http://pear.php.net/) do what u want to do.